# Error Calling Generic Function In Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, syntax-error

So I'm following fpinscala and I have this Object:

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

object List {
    def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match {
        case Nil => 0
        case Cons(x, xs) => x + sum(xs)
    }

    def product(ds: List[Double]): Double = ds match {
        case Nil => 1
        case Cons(x, xs) => x * product(xs)
    }

    def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] =
        if (as.isEmpty) Nil
        else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

    def tail[A](as: List[A]): List[A] = as match {
        case Nil => as
        case Cons(_, xs) => xs 
    }

    def setHead[A](as: List[A], a: A): List[A] = as match {
        case Nil => Cons(a, Nil)
        case Cons(_, xs) => Cons(a, xs)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
        println(tail(List(1,2,3)))
}
```

When I try to run main I get:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int] (in scala.collection.immutable)
 required: List[?]   (in <empty>)
        println(tail(List[Int](1,2,3)))
```

I have followed the book pretty exactly so I don't know what I'm missing here. It says you should now be able to call List(1, 2, 3, 4)  or List("hello", "goodbye") with no issues. But I can't pass that to the function? Some insight on what I'm missing would be appreciated.

Comment: `found : List[Int] (in scala.collection.immutable)` You appear to be mixing the Standard Library `List` with your own code. Try renaming your `List`.

Comment: Now that I did that I am getting:

`error: not found: value QList
  val l = QList(1, 2, 3)`

When I try to do:
`val l = QList(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: Make sure you have renamed both your `List` **class** and your `List` **object** into `QList`. It looks like you only renamed the class here.

Comment: I plugged your code into an IntelliJ worksheet. After renaming _all_ `List` references it compiles with a warning "not runnable program", but it compiles without error.

Answer (score 3):

The code compiles correctly, the only problem I see is that you are declaring the main method in the List companion object and that is incorrect, you should move it to other object:

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

object List {
    def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match {
        case Nil => 0
        case Cons(x, xs) => x + sum(xs)
    }

    def product(ds: List[Double]): Double = ds match {
        case Nil => 1
        case Cons(x, xs) => x * product(xs)
    }

    def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] =
        if (as.isEmpty) Nil
        else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

    def tail[A](as: List[A]): List[A] = as match {
        case Nil => as
        case Cons(_, xs) => xs 
    }

    def setHead[A](as: List[A], a: A): List[A] = as match {
        case Nil => Cons(a, Nil)
        case Cons(_, xs) => Cons(a, xs)
    }
}
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
        println(List.tail(List(1,2,3)))
}
```